# How to use locally served tiles for interactive maps instead of just a png image of tiles

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers

I followed this link and it worked for me..

https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-14-04/

I can serve tiles locally but running it and by just typing the link like for instance - localhost/osm_tiles/0/0/0.png and it gives me an image with a particular zoom level, x and y axis.

Now I have this advanced localized openstreet map example I saw..
http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.1/examples/localized-openstreetmap.html which is of course an advanced custom tile server. Taking the tutorial I got from switch2osm, is it possible for me to create that same kind of tile server?

Comment: What exactly is your question? How to make a dynamic map viewer (->Openlayers or Leaflet) or how to make localized map tiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example uses open cycle map tiles. So yes, you can create and use your own rendering styles.

In switch2osm.org tutorial related section is `Stylesheet configuration`.
You could write mapnik style xml stylesheet or convert it from carto-css project.

This step actually converts carto-css to mapnik xml.

```
carto project.mml > OSMBright.xml
```

You could use base OSM style as an example.
https://github.com/gravitystorm/openstreetmap-carto

And here you could find how OpenCycleMap style looks like https://github.com/tclavier/mapnik